# Shortcut to a website

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome

Is it possibole to make on the desktop shortcuts to some websites. Using Google Chrome.

The websites where I want to link are: Facebook, my webmail and some others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new file in your desktop and paste the following commands. Save it as `askubuntu.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
url="http://www.askubuntu.com"
google-chrome $url
```

Give it executable rights by running this command:

```
chmod +x ~/Desktop/askubuntu.sh
```

Now, just a simple double click on the file will open up Google Chrome with the URL specified in the `url` variable.

Comment: Or just drag the URL to the desktop. Works for me un Ubuntu 14.04 with Unity.

Answer (score 2):

The old GUI dialog is still available if you still want to use this:

Using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> , type

`gnome-desktop-item-edit --create-new ~/Desktop`

This will launch the old GUI dialog and you can create a shortcut on your desktop.

As a prerequisite, `gnome-desktop-item-edit` is installed automatically if you have installed `gnome-shell` or `gnome-shell-fallback`. It is also installed automatically if you have previously installed `gnome-tweak-tool`.

Alternatively, you can install the panel (which installs this module) without too much of the other bulk:

`sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends gnome-panel`

Comment: That looks hard, is there a easier way?

Comment: Not that I know of. Have you tried selecting the link in Chrome, then dragging it to the desktop?